# Is there a way to change the min-height of a viewport in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make this area

[image]

have a minimum height to `0`?
So I can hide it at any time.

Comment: I'm not aware of any setting for this and didn't find anything by searching through settings with "`split`" in them... but maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: @user thanks for checking with me, let's see...
when the height is short like in the screenshot clicking that area will expand the viewport, but clicking the tab will also trigger that expansion so I don't really need to have this visual space. And VSCode doesn't support multirow tabs (just wrap tabs) but I like having two row of tabs (one is my config files and the second is source files)

Comment: Related GitHub issue: [Maximize current editor group (or temporarily hide other editor groups) #8989](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8989). Closest workaround currently is `View: Maximize Editor Group`, which unfortunately doesn't seem to solve the problem in the question asked here.